# Multiple Active Result Set Limitations in the Developer edition of SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

Are there any limitations on Multiple Active Result Sets in the developer edtion of SQL Server 2019?

Comment: Why would you want to use MARS anyway? It indicates a poor use of an ORM, with the classic N+1 problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are no special limits on MARS for the Developer Edition. As per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2022?view=sql-server-ver16) (emphasis added),

> SQL Server Developer edition lets developers build any kind of application on top of SQL Server. *It includes all the functionality of Enterprise edition*, but is licensed for use as a development and test system, not as a production server.

Just remember that MARS configuration doesn't work out of the box - it needs to be [enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets) on the client-side by passing proper parameter in the connection string.

Comment: thank you, yes I've read that too. I still have doubts though that  Developer isn't limited in any way. Number of cores? Number of concurrent sessions? Memory.

Comment: _For features supported by Developer and Evaluation editions, see features listed for the SQL Server Enterprise edition in the tables below._ ibid. If you don't believe MS documentation, ask your Microsoft vendor.

Comment: @CraigEfrein, besides licensing, the only difference between Enterprise and Developer editions AFAIK is the Distributed Replay, where dev edition is limited to one.

Comment: @CraigEfrein FWIW, to re-emphasize the other comments, Developer Edition *is* Enterprise Edition essentially, sans licensing rights. This is so developers can fully explore the capabilities of SQL Server (and from a marketing perspective perhaps even get them hooked on an Enterprise-level feature, IMO). Standard Edition and Express Edition are the limited editions.

Comment: I have encountered a migration from 2008 standard to 2019 dev edition, and there appears to be some limitation as to the number of pooled connections. I'm still gathering info.

Comment: @CraigEfrein, connection pooling is part of the client API or middleware, not SQL Server server software.

Comment: @CraigEfrein If you can demonstrate such a thing I'd be interested to know, I doubt it exists (as a Developer Edition specific thing).

Comment: @CraigEfrein: It might be the _application_ as Dan Guzman points out. I've seen a service desk product that queried `@@version` and looked for standard/enterprise. For anything else, its installer decided that SQL Server edition was not supported (yeah, I looked inside the MSI). Maybe the app you are working has similar a thing.